# Missing symbols from LayarSDK in the simulator

Tags: ios, linker, layar

I'm including the Layar SDK framework into my app (version 8.0) and everything works fine on a device.

However, I can't run the app on a simulator anymore - I don't mind Layar not working (there's no camera after all!) but I do need it to compile for continual integration, automated tests etc (not to mention developing on the train top/from work!)

The linker gives me these errors :

```
ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/username/Documents/appname/libs/MPOAuth/libMPOAuthMobile.a, missing required architecture i386 in file /Users/username/Documents/appname/libs/MPOAuth/libMPOAuthMobile.a (2 slices)
ld: warning: ignoring file local/LayarSDK/LayarSDK.framework/LayarSDK, missing required architecture i386 in file local/LayarSDK/LayarSDK.framework/LayarSDK (2 slices)
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_LayarSDK", referenced from:
    objc-class-ref in MYAppDelegate.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
```

Checking, the LayarSDK doesn't contain `i386`, it only contains `armv7` and `armv7s`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution is pretty clumsy - if anyone has a better idea, please let me know!

I compile this file (`LayarSimulatorStub.m`) into my app :

```
#if TARGET_IPHONE_SIMULATOR

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface LayarSDK : NSObject

@end

@implementation LayarSDK

+ (id)layarSDKWithConsumerKey:(id)a andConsumerSecret:(id)b andDelegate:(id)c { return nil; }
- (id)init { return nil; }
- (id)initWithConsumerKey:(id)a andConsumerSecret:(id)b andDelegate:(id)c { return nil; }

@end

#endif
```

Now, there *is* an `i386` symbol `LayarSDK`. It just returns `nil` from all it's constructors. The app now compiles with Layar disabled.

The conditional compilation means that it's not present for the device architectures so there are no linker errors.